# Does Unity store temporary autosaves for scripts? If not, how do I avoid data corruption

Tags: unity

My PC lost power in the midst of a save(twice in a row) and I've lost my scene setup as well as a script(its contents actually). I would like to know if there are any fail-safes for saving files. If not, how would I prevent future data loss/corruption.

Comment: Go get a new computer lol... this time get a Mac ;)

Comment: At the same price of a Mac he can get better hardware and an UPS. :>

Comment: @Savlon Suggesting a mac with no real metrics surrounding this problem is rather obnoxious. Apple mostly just provides black boxes, if anything I'd stay far away from Apple.

Comment: @Sidar https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joke lol... you should try relaxing some time, you might actually get some real face to face human interaction.

Comment: @Savlon I'm glad you put effort in attempting a joke. Please tone down on the personal attacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Professional software developers (not just game developers and not just Unity developers) usually save themselves from this problem (and many more) by using a [version control tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control). Whenever you accomplished something in your project, you save your progress by creating a revision. When your project (or parts of it) get corrupted, you just revert to the last revision. Think of them as savegames for software development - when you get killed, you just reload :)

They are also essential if you are working in a team to prevent you from overwriting each others work.

Unity offers special integration support for [Perforce](https://www.perforce.com/solutions/version-control) and [PlasticSCM](https://www.plasticscm.com/). But if you would like to use a free solution, you can also use a technology-agnostic version control tool which just operates on your filesystem, like Git, Mercurial or Subversion.

For more information, check [the chapter in the Unity documentation about version control](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VersionControl.html).

Comment: I'm always surprised that no one mentions [smartmerge](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SmartMerge.html) directly. I know it's in the pages but it's often overlooked. It's the best thing for merging scenes and prefabs.

Answer (score 0):

For scripts you're in the middle of editing, I know Visual Studio has some amount of auto-save/recovery functionality. Once relaunched, it will prompt you if you want to recover the auto-saved version.

I mostly encounter it when Visual Studio crashes in the middle of typing, which is a perfectly normal thing for a text editor to do in 2018 I guess? :/

Comment: I work with VS on a daily basis and it never crashes :P Is it because it's coupled with Unity in your case?

Comment: Couldn't say! I sincerely wish I had your experience with it though.